# Importing MATLAB engine on Python using TextMate - Python quits unexpectedly

Tags: python, matlab, python-2.7, matlab-engine

I am trying to call a MATLAB function from a Python script. I installed the MATLAB Engine API as instructed by the Mathworks website, and then importing the engine in my script using:

```
import matlab.engine
```

(using TextMate on Mac OS.) However I was getting an error saying the engine installation was corrupted. I realised that Python 3.5 is not supported by the engine, so I uninstalled Python and installed version 2.7. From this point on every time I try to import the engine that way, Python quits unexpectedly. Weirdly enough, it ONLY happens using TextMate, but not using IDLE, for example. 
This is the error I get:

```
Process:               Python [3609] Path:                  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python Identifier:            Python Version:               2.7.10 (2.7.10) Code Type:             X86-64 (Native) Parent Process:        ??? [3604] Responsible:           Python [3609] User ID:               503

Date/Time:             2016-03-30 17:58:26.469 +0200 OS Version:       Mac OS X 10.11.3 (15D21) Report Version:        11 Anonymous UUID:     F829ADA5-2D7E-CDCB-4599-4A9C227DE9C5


Time Awake Since Boot: 3400 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000 Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 000000010fd24000-000000010fd25000 [    4K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 0   ???        000000000000000000 0 + 0 1   libpython2.7.dylib             0x0000000110e7fb17 PyEval_GetGlobals + 23 2   libpython2.7.dylib        0x0000000110ea3da2 PyImport_Import + 50 3   libpython2.7.dylib          0x0000000110ea3fd8 PyImport_ImportModule + 40 4   matlabengineforpython2_7.so       0x000000011053dcf7 initmatlabengineforpython2_7 + 23 5   org.python.python              0x000000010fdc44b3 _PyImport_LoadDynamicModule + 140 6   org.python.python              0x000000010fdc31b1 0x10fd29000 + 631217 7   org.python.python               0x000000010fdc2d77 0x10fd29000 + 630135 8   org.python.python               0x000000010fdc1f5b PyImport_ImportModuleLevel + 1139 9   org.python.python              0x000000010fda7a0a 0x10fd29000 + 518666 10  org.python.python           0x000000010fdafa0b PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13400 11  org.python.python     0x000000010fdac3c1 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1583 12  org.python.python       0x000000010fdb24ae 0x10fd29000 + 562350 13  org.python.python           0x000000010fdaf30c PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 11609 14  org.python.python     0x000000010fdac3c1 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1583 15  org.python.python       0x000000010fdabd8c PyEval_EvalCode + 54 16  org.python.python           0x000000010fdc0a37 PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx + 241 17  org.python.python                0x000000010fdc374f 0x10fd29000 + 632655 18  org.python.python               0x000000010fdc39d4 0x10fd29000 + 633300 19  org.python.python               0x000000010fdc31b1 0x10fd29000 + 631217 20  org.python.python               0x000000010fdc2d77 0x10fd29000 + 630135 21  org.python.python           0x000000010fdc1f93 PyImport_ImportModuleLevel + 1195 22  org.python.python              0x000000010fda7a0a 0x10fd29000 + 518666 23  org.python.python               0x000000010fd33202 PyObject_Call + 99 24  org.python.python                 0x000000010fdb1e83 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 165 25  org.python.python                0x000000010fdae2ec PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 7481 26  org.python.python      0x000000010fdac3c1 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1583 27  org.python.python       0x000000010fdabd8c PyEval_EvalCode + 54 28  org.python.python           0x000000010fdcba42 0x10fd29000 + 666178 29  org.python.python           0x000000010fdcbae5 PyRun_FileExFlags + 133 30  org.python.python        0x000000010fdcb634 PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 698 31  org.python.python              0x000000010fddd011 Py_Main + 3137 32  libdyld.dylib                     0x00007fff8d4725ad start + 1

Thread 1: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff88c8d6de
__workq_kernreturn + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff884f7729 _pthread_wqthread + 1283 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff884f5365 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff88c8dff6 kevent_qos + 10 1   libdispatch.dylib                0x00007fff8e105099 _dispatch_mgr_invoke
+ 216 2   libdispatch.dylib                 0x00007fff8e104d01 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 3: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff88c8d6de
__workq_kernreturn + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff884f7729 _pthread_wqthread + 1283 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff884f5365 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff88c8d6de
__workq_kernreturn + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff884f7729 _pthread_wqthread + 1283 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff884f5365 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):   rax: 0x0000000110f68540  rbx: 0x0000000113829030  rcx: 0x0000000000000008  rdx: 0x00000001138290c0   rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x00007fff4feda420  rsp: 0x00007fff4feda418   r8: 0x0000000110eaad4c   r9: 0x0000000110f7f0b0  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x000000000294015c   r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000113829030  r15: 0x000000010fe613f8   rip: 0x0000000000000000  rfl: 0x0000000000010206  cr2: 0x0000000000000000    Logical CPU:     3 Error Code:      0x00000014 Trap Number:     14


Binary Images:
       0x10fd24000 -        0x10fd24fff  org.python.python (2.7.10 - 2.7.10) <C517A5DB-2554-3B18-B185-056F652B2F55> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
       0x10fd29000 -        0x10fe1aff7  org.python.python (2.7.10 - 2.7.10) <ABBA93BD-FB4A-34EB-8362-650D0FF6C1A1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
       0x1101e3000 -        0x1101e4fff  _locale.so (94) <6C7EB7F6-222C-3BE7-8D65-B9DCBD8931FF> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_locale.so
       0x110269000 -        0x11026cfff  operator.so (94) <1A0F7C26-2E64-3EBB-BEC8-44F96DA05FFC> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/operator.so
       0x110273000 -        0x110275fff  _collections.so (94) <D7112DEC-DD54-37AF-8D00-135B06649B77> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_collections.so
       0x11027c000 -        0x110280fff  itertools.so (94) <49860150-735A-3C9B-996B-9B1E9D310EC8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/itertools.so
       0x11028a000 -        0x11028bfff  _heapq.so (94) <23E666D1-0260-30E3-8291-A68C641F1171> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_heapq.so
       0x1102d1000 -        0x1102e0fff  _io.so (94) <6FDA36F1-9F87-35BF-8D82-4A2303236D3F> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
       0x1102f1000 -        0x1102f4ff7  math.so (94) <1637540A-A769-3732-8C50-9BE3E0455636> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/math.so
       0x1102fb000 -        0x1102fdfff  binascii.so (94) <5F4A49D3-3606-3A95-836E-0D75915C72B9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/binascii.so
       0x110302000 -        0x110303fff  _hashlib.so (94) <CFB92476-1544-3B3F-8366-5B389B21A235> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_hashlib.so
       0x110309000 -        0x11030cfff  _struct.so (94) <62E94AB5-0016-33B1-A67C-3170776EC19D> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_struct.so
       0x110313000 -        0x110314ff7  _random.so (94) <E9434EBB-9BB4-3960-A1FB-D9029D7BAEAB> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_random.so
       0x110319000 -        0x11031afff  cStringIO.so (94) <575AABB8-95E5-3D71-961E-D7609D0E860A> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/cStringIO.so
       0x110320000 -        0x110321fff  fcntl.so (94) <86FEA0C2-CD20-399E-B4DB-2678042BB0AA> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/fcntl.so
       0x110326000 -        0x110327ff7  time.so (94) <36B871D5-4881-3ACE-B4B0-ADB6151F938C> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/time.so
       0x11036e000 -        0x110371ff7  strop.so (94) <1D059A80-5692-3A3E-8085-44E6761CC4A2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/strop.so
       0x110377000 -        0x11037eff7  _socket.so (94) <81DD00EE-9A93-3617-AF7A-57ECAF4363BE> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_socket.so
       0x110389000 -        0x11038afff  _functools.so (94) <98357790-1F0D-39B3-8F10-54B90B973529> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_functools.so
       0x11038f000 -        0x110398fff  _ssl.so (94) <199B2179-BD39-305A-9224-4C22EF916DD0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.so
       0x110424000 -        0x110424fff  _scproxy.so (94) <BBC0BFC5-0CB4-35C5-86DC-DD02D596535C> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_scproxy.so
       0x1104e9000 -        0x1104edfff  array.so (94) <18437978-86DB-387E-887D-9B130168981F> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/array.so
       0x110534000 -        0x110557ff8 +matlabengineforpython2_7.so (0) <5C149CA8-A359-3955-AB38-6174FE929864> /Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/extern/engines/python/dist/matlab/engine/maci64/matlabengineforpython2_7.so
       0x110575000 -        0x11068aff2 +libmx.dylib (0) <E1C01B4F-0E77-3E72-8405-740BFFCB3346> /Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/maci64/libmx.dylib
       0x110706000 -        0x1107d5ffa +libmwfl.dylib (0) <F0669917-1751-380B-9DE9-9E1EAFFB3C7E> /Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/maci64/libmwfl.dylib
       0x1108ca000 -        0x110939ff1 +libmwi18n.dylib (0) <7C560066-6954-37FE-A248-E109E838E078> /Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/maci64/libmwi18n.dylib
       0x110983000 -        0x1109a0ff5 +libmwengine_api.dylib (0) <4F494FDF-3B37-309B-B74C-D17DF239C450> /Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/maci64/libmwengine_api.dylib
       0x1109ba000 -        0x110b08ffe +libmwmlutil.dylib (0) <FAE9071E-7D39-3333-B03A-9FA549879AD0> /Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/maci64/libmwmlutil.dylib
       0x110dad000 -        0x110db7ff7 +libmwcpp11compat.dylib (0) <ADFE9039-E706-3826-B321-57B530C94012> /Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/maci64/libmwcpp11compat.dylib
       0x110dc6000 -        0x110f36ff7 +libpython2.7.dylib (2.7) <54D8DBAC-FF5C-0D3A-A11A-6419EBC941C3> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/libpython2.7.dylib
       0x111006000 -        0x111053ffd +libut.dylib (0) <75124867-D829-3468-A71B-A51F3DD9E893> /Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/maci64/libut.dylib
       0x1110a7000 -        0x111109ff7 +libboost_log.dylib (0) <265AF1D4-38CF-3988-95A7-4DAB30FD78F9> /Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/maci64/libboost_log.dylib
       0x1111a9000 -        0x1111b5ffa +libboost_thread.dylib (0) <E3546590-F780-314D-8232-F7F500EE96F2> /Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/maci64/libboost_thread.dylib
       0x1111c9000 -        0x1112cdffb +libicuuc.54.dylib (0) <C2291C1B-BA99-3F89-8AE0-D82C304F22E3> /Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/maci64/libicuuc.54.dylib
       0x11132f000 -        0x11134cff7 +libtbb.dylib (0) <7E612A1E-6A0A-368D-A249-7BC6F8F1D09F> /Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/maci64/libtbb.dylib
       0x111361000 -        0x11136efff +libtbbmalloc.dylib (0) <92A6DC41-82A3-3F6E-A2CB-C251D24C93CE> /Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/maci64/libtbbmalloc.dylib
       0x111398000 -        0x111398ffd +libmwresource_core.dylib (0) <0682ECBD-6C67-330E-8692-26ADDC0D82D8> /Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/maci64/libmwresource_core.dylib
       0x11139b000 -        0x1113abff3 +libboost_filesystem.dylib (0) <ACE643E6-0555-33B5-B5B5-4E169777D944> /Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/maci64/libboost_filesystem.dylib
       0x1113bd000 -        0x1113beff7 +libboost_system.dylib (0) <6BC301FC-1026-3D5D-A644-D9308E2135FE> /Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/maci64/libboost_system.dylib
       0x1113c1000 -        0x1113dafff  libexpat.1.dylib (12.20.1) <AA76E4CF-52F5-3CF9-907B-FBB80BAFB125> /usr/lib/libexpat.1.dylib
       0x1113e4000 -        0x11154affb +libicui18n.54.dylib (0) <441B83B5-CD28-3677-9AF2-246ACB4DA620> /Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/maci64/libicui18n.54.dylib
       0x111610000 -        0x111617ffb +libicuio.54.dylib (0) <81462A69-BABB-34D3-8E0A-4EA7471A8393> /Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/maci64/libicuio.54.dylib
       0x11161e000 -        0x112e49fff +libicudata.54.dylib (0) <B9C8B350-AB40-3429-A96B-1BCB68982646> /Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/maci64/libicudata.54.dylib
       0x112e4b000 -        0x112f5dfe7 +libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (0) <5605229A-1B87-34ED-81AE-C9B4710FE073> /Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/maci64/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
       0x112fce000 -        0x112fd2ff5 +libboost_date_time.dylib (0) <E9678FDC-5B38-37B6-B377-8D633D2273B4> /Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/maci64/libboost_date_time.dylib
       0x112fde000 -        0x113088ff9 +libboost_regex.dylib (0) <86331A42-3EAC-3E7F-92A3-0CB64FA2D2BF> /Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/maci64/libboost_regex.dylib
       0x1130f9000 -        0x11311eff8 +libboost_serialization.dylib (0) <37AFC49A-512B-3B0D-B1A4-BDA4FAAD5A06> /Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/maci64/libboost_serialization.dylib
       0x113186000 -        0x113191ff1 +libboost_signals.dylib (0) <43065B1E-95E0-3B06-9A51-E0F9B20514D6> /Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/maci64/libboost_signals.dylib
       0x11319f000 -        0x11327effb +libmwmvm.dylib (0) <6808E810-B93E-38CD-8415-0EA652997400> /Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/maci64/libmwmvm.dylib
       0x113417000 -        0x113598ffd +libmwms.dylib (0) <D7CC156B-159C-3540-A524-3A852F698459> /Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/maci64/libmwms.dylib
       0x1137fd000 -        0x113807ff3 +libboost_iostreams.dylib (0) <0A2B5ABE-CE27-370B-89C4-154257FD6C52> /Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/maci64/libboost_iostreams.dylib
    0x7fff6ceef000 -     0x7fff6cf26007  dyld (360.19) <9D05FDF4-65CE-3B53-86D4-ABE1A5BF35F3> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff86336000 -     0x7fff86338ff7  libquarantine.dylib (80) <163CF63A-7455-3D1F-AE57-8C4475A9204C> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
    0x7fff86def000 -     0x7fff86e50ff7  libsystem_network.dylib (583.20.10) <865FE79A-A22D-3733-A14F-FC7B37F3AECD> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
    0x7fff86e82000 -     0x7fff86ee0fff  com.apple.SystemConfiguration (1.14 - 1.14) <5A70115B-E346-3EBD-A617-9A11C61EEF2E> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
    0x7fff87669000 -     0x7fff87671fff  libcopyfile.dylib (127) <F5133269-0B22-388C-A57C-079667B6291E> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
    0x7fff884f4000 -     0x7fff884fdff7  libsystem_pthread.dylib (138.10.4) <327CECD0-B881-3153-8FCC-4FD4818B7F16> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    0x7fff88bb2000 -     0x7fff88bb9ff7  libcompiler_rt.dylib (62) <D3C4AB40-23B4-3BC6-8C38-5B8758D14E80> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
    0x7fff88c76000 -     0x7fff88c94fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib (3248.30.4) <9CEB6C3B-1CAF-3C32-A9FD-93BC72CBCEA1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x7fff89192000 -     0x7fff89193fff  com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent (2.0 - 25) <0239494E-FEFE-39BC-9FC7-E251BA5128F1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.framework/Versions/A/TrustEvaluationAgent
    0x7fff89477000 -     0x7fff894bdff7  libauto.dylib (186) <999E610F-41FC-32A3-ADCA-5EC049B65DFB> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
    0x7fff89596000 -     0x7fff89597fff  libsystem_secinit.dylib (20) <FD6ECF2C-1489-32CA-981B-9045B5EB1FAA> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_secinit.dylib
    0x7fff896bc000 -     0x7fff898c9ffb  libicucore.A.dylib (551.41) <CFFD7342-A7D6-323A-AC14-B9EECF6EFFED> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x7fff89bf8000 -     0x7fff89c14ff7  libsystem_malloc.dylib (67) <9EECAB18-F025-34C4-8E32-7EFFA6720EFC> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
    0x7fff89c15000 -     0x7fff89cfcff7  libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib (59) <ED1C2A26-8FFC-30FF-8726-FF952EF94ADF> /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
    0x7fff8a22b000 -     0x7fff8a23cff7  libz.1.dylib (61.20.1) <B3EBB42F-48E3-3287-9F0D-308E04D407AC> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x7fff8a39d000 -     0x7fff8a3a8ff7  libcommonCrypto.dylib (60075.20.1) <766BC3F5-41F3-3315-BABC-72718A98EA92> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
    0x7fff8a3d4000 -     0x7fff8a3d4ff7  libkeymgr.dylib (28) <09397E01-6066-3179-A50C-2CE666FDA929> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
    0x7fff8a60e000 -     0x7fff8a637fff  libsystem_info.dylib (477.20.1) <6513635B-4ADE-3B45-BF63-ED7AC565B0C9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
    0x7fff8b4e7000 -     0x7fff8b574fff  libsystem_c.dylib (1082.20.4) <EAB38A6C-8671-3B13-B500-90EC1B912063> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
    0x7fff8ca97000 -     0x7fff8ca99ff7  libsystem_configuration.dylib (802.20.7) <5FD79070-36CC-3D02-BEA7-BB5D2AE97D5D> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
    0x7fff8d46f000 -     0x7fff8d472ffb  libdyld.dylib (360.19) <AA629043-C6F6-32FE-8007-E3478E99ACA7> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
    0x7fff8d4c6000 -     0x7fff8d53dfe7  libcorecrypto.dylib (335.20.1) <C6BD205F-4ECE-37EE-BCAB-A76F39CDCFFA> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
    0x7fff8db17000 -     0x7fff8db20ff3  libsystem_notify.dylib (150.20.3) <243FADE1-255A-3B78-8033-F336CD64B817> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
    0x7fff8dcde000 -     0x7fff8dcdfffb  libSystem.B.dylib (1226.10.1) <5A4257EF-3145-3BB3-87A4-0D2404A9462D> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff8dd33000 -     0x7fff8dd44ff7  libsystem_trace.dylib (201.10.3) <B485369F-E3A1-319E-998C-89AAF606079E> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
    0x7fff8e0fd000 -     0x7fff8e12afff  libdispatch.dylib (501.20.1) <324C9189-2AF3-3356-847F-6F4CE1C6E901> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
    0x7fff8eef6000 -     0x7fff8f36cfff  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 1256.14) <768A7FB7-9143-3148-8591-7C6ED3162D35> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff8fe50000 -     0x7fff8fe58ffb  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (625.20.4) <945B5FB1-DA91-3D45-A961-A8FAD53C1E7E> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
    0x7fff9032c000 -     0x7fff90362fff  libssl.0.9.8.dylib (59) <DC4B66A8-AFED-33A9-A5B8-D2088C6EF5B2> /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib
    0x7fff90525000 -     0x7fff90528ff7  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (460.30.1) <3E0036AF-FC64-3352-8DA4-6B550C2C2562> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
    0x7fff90693000 -     0x7fff90694ffb  libremovefile.dylib (41) <B8D1A5FC-CFD5-3AAB-8A10-14DDC129710A> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
    0x7fff906e2000 -     0x7fff906e3fff  libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib (100) <4243B6B4-21E9-355B-9C5A-95A216233B96> /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib
    0x7fff90b18000 -     0x7fff90b2fff7  libsystem_asl.dylib (322.30.1) <9B500E4E-E462-321E-828E-5524DC984C1B> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
    0x7fff914ff000 -     0x7fff91528fff  libxpc.dylib (756.20.4) <61AB4610-9304-354C-9E9B-D57198AE9866> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
    0x7fff91d2e000 -     0x7fff91d44ff7  libsystem_coretls.dylib (83.20.8) <75C97D88-0A63-3093-AE83-DE33EB7405CE> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coretls.dylib
    0x7fff925e3000 -     0x7fff925e8ff7  libmacho.dylib (875.1) <CB745E1F-4885-3F96-B38B-2093DF488FD5> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
    0x7fff92613000 -     0x7fff9263cfff  libc++abi.dylib (125) <DCCC8177-3D09-35BC-9784-2A04FEC4C71B> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
    0x7fff92756000 -     0x7fff92758fff  libsystem_coreservices.dylib (19.2) <1B3F5AFC-FFCD-3ECB-8B9A-5538366FB20D> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
    0x7fff931ea000 -     0x7fff93555657  libobjc.A.dylib (680) <58CB8CFC-7DBD-3A53-BD72-A42FF799B21E> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7fff93921000 -     0x7fff93950ffb  libsystem_m.dylib (3105) <26655445-CA97-321E-B221-801CB378D1AA> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
    0x7fff9691a000 -     0x7fff9696dff7  libc++.1.dylib (120.1) <8FC3D139-8055-3498-9AC5-6467CB7F4D14> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
    0x7fff96b11000 -     0x7fff96b12fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib (65) <49D42329-7DE9-3413-92C3-A473A7E9CF35> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
    0x7fff96b79000 -     0x7fff96b81fff  libsystem_networkextension.dylib (385.20.6) <DC8A102A-BF02-31A4-8914-65C34DF6B592> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
    0x7fff98fb8000 -     0x7fff98fc0fe7  libsystem_platform.dylib (74.10.3) <D3A27E10-7F08-3603-ACC8-7A92B2C04BAB> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
    0x7fff99f55000 -     0x7fff99f55ff7  liblaunch.dylib (756.20.4) <EDF719D6-D2BB-38DD-8C94-4272BEFDA2CD> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
    0x7fff9a50d000 -     0x7fff9a511fff  libcache.dylib (75) <6B245C0A-F3EA-383B-A542-5B0D0456A41B> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
    0x7fff9a512000 -     0x7fff9a512ff7  libunc.dylib (29) <1D0F8265-F026-3CBD-93D3-F8DF14FFCE68> /usr/lib/system/libunc.dylib
    0x7fff9bda0000 -     0x7fff9bda5ff3  libunwind.dylib (35.3) <124E0F05-2350-3774-A32C-7F5BF38EDE73> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
    0x7fff9c829000 -     0x7fff9c839fff  libbsm.0.dylib (34) <7E14504C-A8B0-3574-B6EB-5D5FABC72926> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib

External Modification Summary:   Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0   Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0   Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 2381
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary: ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=157.6M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=157.6M(100%) Writable regions: Total=62.4M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=62.4M(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION  REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  =======  Activity Tracing                  2048K        2  Dispatch continuations            8192K        2  Kernel Alloc Once                    4K        2  MALLOC              
37.4M       11  MALLOC guard page                   16K        4  Process Corpse Info               2048K        2  STACK GUARD         
56.0M        6  Stack                             9824K        6  VM_ALLOCATE                       2836K       10 
__DATA                            5300K      113 
__LINKEDIT                       103.2M       54 
__TEXT                            54.4M      101 
__UNICODE                          552K        2  shared memory                       28K        6 
===========                     =======  =======  TOTAL                            281.2M      307 

Model: MacBookPro9,2, BootROM MBP91.00D3.B0C, 2 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.9 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.2f41 Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533643465238432D50422020 Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533643465238432D50422020 AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xF5), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.94.136.1a1) Bluetooth: Version 4.4.3f4 16616, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1 Serial ATA Device: Samsung SSD 840 EVO 120GB, 120.03 GB Serial ATA Device: APPLE HDD HTS547575A9E384, 750.16 GB USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus USB Device: Hub USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in) USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus USB Device: Hub USB Device: Hub USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad USB Device: IR Receiver USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 25.1
```

Comment: if this is reproducible, you might wanna report this bug directly to MathWorks.

Comment: The thing is, it was working before I installed Python 2.7 (The engine itself wasn't, but that's a known issue). Phython wasn't crashing though!I think the problem might be that I only deleted the Phython 3.5 folder from Applications instead of removing all the other files from /usr/bin and Library, so it's possible that there could be some problem due to that. However I uninstalled both deleting everything, reinstalled 2.7 and it still gives me this problem.

Comment: you mentioned TextMate and IDLE crashing? I'm not sure but consider running your script from the command line `python myscript.py`

Comment: IDLE doesn't crash, TextMate does, which is weird. I'm just not a big fan of using IDLE, hence why I was trying to find a solution in order to use TextMate.(I did try to reinstall Textmate, no success)